# Hide Properties for Ctrl+Comma (Navigate to) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm a big fan of the Navigate to window (Ctrl + Comma) to navigate to classes and files.

Problem for me is that it also shows *Properties*, *Fields* and *Methods* that match your keyword.

In a large codebase that means the navigate to window is flooded with *members* while I'm mainly using this to look for **Classes**.

**Question:**

Is it possible to hide Properties and other Members in the 'Navigate to' window?

I've looked into Settings but with no luck to this moment.

*Note: I'm not using Resharper and looking for a Visual Studio native solution*

Comment: This is definitely **not** an answer to **your** question but I still want to offer an option that might be helpful, although getting outside the scope of your requirement. There's a reason that most C# devs use R# and that's precisely those small, quirky, helpful features - those are missing in VS (because of some insane and incomprehensible reason!) but they are implemented in R#. If one could do all the smooth stuff with vanilla VS, nobody would be using R#. Trust me. May I encourage you to use R#? (You always have an option to write your own plugins, of course...)

Comment: Hi Konrad, thanks for your answer. We're a bootstrapped company and at this stage of our company it's hard to afford 200 to 300 dollars per year per user just for this single feature. I know there is tons of other stuff in Resharper, but this is by the biggest feature that I'm missing in native VS (note we use VS community edition)

Comment: I see the issue. It's actually 150 Euro after start-up discount and you might also do some open source deliveries to qualify for a free license but that doesn't resolves your original issue, of course. I guess, you'll have to do without the option. Or put some time aside and write an own plugin doing just that. Sorry for not being able to help you more.

Comment: Hi @KonradViltersten, your not just helping me, but also all others that will see this question through google. Thanks that you take your time to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 they've added a really useful feature where you can type an 'f' in front of your search to only look for files.

Like: `f banana pancakes` searches for only files with banana pancakes. You can also use `t` for types and there are some other really good new options.

This is available also for the community edition. If you're using an older version of Visual Studio I recommend taking the effort to upgrade.