# Avoid seeing multiple results for the same thing in Visual Studio's Navigate To (Ctrl+comma) box?

Tags: visual-studio

The "Navigate To" box in Visual Studio is highly useful; I like it better even than Resharper's similar feature.

However, one drawback is that items show up in there multiple times because there are multiple object types that match.  For example, if I search for one of my classes Foo, I get a match for the file Foo.cs, a match for the class Foo (same file), and a match for every constructor of Foo.  Now I follow the convention of one class per file, so these three matches are always the same item; every time I search, I have to think about which one to choose, though in fact all three options are conceptually the same.

[image: making me think about a trivial choice]

Is there any way to consolidate multiple types that are really the same thing in Visual Studio's Navigate To (Ctrl+comma) box? A different but slightly related question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081337/hide-properties-for-ctrlcomma-navigate-to-in-visual-studio).

Comment: I could swear that in a previous version I could see the buttons for only searching files/properties/classes etc. But, just as you say, there's nothing like that in the current version of R#. You could use *Go to file*, *Go to symbol*, *Go to action* instead. Check the shortcuts for those in the menu under *Navigate*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the match for the file you could try putting an at sign ("@") before your search string. This should restrict your search to symbols, avoiding the results from the file system.

**Example**

Results without "@":
[image]

Results with "@":
[image]